# What are "exotic character sets"?

Tags: c++, character

I am reading an c++ document, it said as this,

> Wide characters are used mainly to
>   represent non-English or exotic
>   character sets.

What's the exactly meaning for **exotic character sets**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it has no "technical" meaning, it's used as in "strange" or "unusual" character sets.

Since we're talking about wide characters, in general we are actually talking about Unicode; I'd say that [Cuneiform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuneiform_%28Unicode_block%29) or Klingon<sup>1</sup> could be considered as "exotic character sets". Or even those Unicode blocks not intended for languages, but for symbols of various nature ([mathematical symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode), [arrows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_%28symbol%29#Arrows_in_Unicode), [alchemical symbols](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F700.pdf), ...).

---

1. Not actually included in the Unicode standard, but available in the PUA of some fonts ([link](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Test_Klingon.html)).

Comment: Unicode even includes obscure languages like Sanskrit, Linear-B and Ugaritic, to name precious few. Their goal seems to be to support every known written language on Earth.

Comment: @greyfade: given that Sanskrit is the official language of at least one region in the world, I don't consider it "obscure" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskrit).  It's also of important cultural heritage to be able to digitalize historical documents written in archaic languages in their original form!

Answer (score 2):

I think the author means characters such as : `§ ¨ © ¢ ¡ U ï ð ¥ ¦  â ß à á â ã ¶ æ`  and suchlikes!

Comment: All of those characters are found in common single-byte character sets, including ISO Latin-1.  Some may be non-English but they are not exotic.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe special charset that are used mainly for printing symbols or older charset as IBM's [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Binary_Coded_Decimal_Interchange_Code).